# Unable to save changes after merging features in QGIS

Tags: qgis, editing, merge, spatialite

I have a Spatialite layer with two features, the result of a QuickOSM search.  I'd like to merge them into a single feature. Before editing, the layer looks like this:

[image]

I can enable editing for the layer, select the features, and use the "Merge Selected Features" tool to merge them, which apparently does the right thing, and results in:

[image]

Which is exactly what I want. But when I attempt to save the changes, I get this error:

```
Could not commit changes to layer name_Camp Greenough

Errors: ERROR: 2 feature(s) not deleted.
  
  Provider errors:
      OGR error deleting feature 1: sqlite3_exec(DELETE FROM 'camp_greenough' WHERE "ogc_fid" = 1) failed: no such table: main.idx_camp_greenough_GEOMETRY
      OGR error deleting feature 2: sqlite3_exec(DELETE FROM 'camp_greenough' WHERE "ogc_fid" = 2) failed: no such table: main.idx_camp_greenough_GEOMETRY
```

Inspecting the layer file with `sqlite3`, there is indeed a table named `camp_greenough` that has a `GEOMETRY` column. There is no `idx_camp_greenough_GEOMETRY` index. Why is QGIS expecting one?

Answer (score 2):

While I hope that someone comes along with an explanation about what was going on, I was able to work around the problem by exporting the layers as a geopackage and adding that instead. With that change I was able both to merge features **and** save the changes.